# Modal popup border disappears when css background applied

Tags: asp.net, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the Ajax Modal Popup Extender to display a panel as a modal popup.  I've applied a CSS class to the panel and everything displays fine.  However, when I add the `BackgroundCssClass` property to my popup extender, the border on my panel does not show up.  The modal background displays properly and everything else in the panel remains the same, but I can't get the border to display.  What might be causing this?

****CSS****

```
.PopupPanel
{             
width: 75%;
height: 55%;
text-align: center;    
padding: 5px;
overflow: auto;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 8px;
border-color: #0055A5;    
background-color: White;    
}

.ModalBackground
{
background-color: rgba(170,170,174,0.5);    
}
```

****ASPX****

```
<asp:Panel ID="InputPanel" runat="server" CssClass="PopupPanel">

        <asp:Label ID="HeaderLabel" runat="server" 
            Text="[text here]" 
            Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>

        <br />            
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="85%" 
            Height="65%" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>                        
        <br />


        <asp:Button ID="okButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
            CssClass="genericButton" />
        <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" 
            CssClass="genericButton" />
</asp:Panel>

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" 
    PopupControlID="InputPanel" TargetControlID="PasteButton" 
    BackgroundCssClass="ModalBackground" PopupDragHandleControlID="HeaderLabel">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```